# Copying persistent data across db sessions/units of work

Tags: c#, orm, devexpress

I use DevExpress' XPO ORM, but I suspect that this applies to many other ORMs and this happens to me all of the time and it's starting to get annoying.

The situation is:

- 1 form with a UnitOfWork used to populate user controls etc. with data from the db. (eg. a user settings form)
- a dialog window with a UnitOfWork used to populate user controls. (eg. a permissions screen)

The resolutions that I can think of aren't ideal. Keep in mind that I can't copy objects across sessions/units of work in XPO (as far as I can tell).

1. I don't want to just create the the persistent objects in the dialog and commit them with the dialog's unit of work, because then the user can't cancel out of the form without making changes (unless I went back to the DB and deleted the object persisted in the dialog)
2. Forcing all of the dialogs in the software to take a reference to a unit of work in the constructor smells terrible.
3. Having to re-create objects in the form that were created in the dialog smells terrible as well.

what else can I do?

Comment: "The situation is:" ... The resolutions that I can think of" - where is the question? Can you explain the issue first? Shortly, you must definitely edit the question.

Comment: Apologies. I assumed that "I'm not sure what else I can do." implied a request for other ideas that I hadn't thought of.

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but may help others:
The solution to your problem is to use a [Nested Units of Work](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument2113).